# Rig not working

Tags: rigging

I have made a manikin and rigged it but the connection lines of the bones don't make sense and the pelvis bone moves the whole thing. (not what I intended)
[image]

Comment: Please provide more information about your problem. Maybe you can share images or even the blend file. Describe what do you exactly want to achieve.

Comment: I've tried to add the blender file but it didn't work

Comment: You can upload it here for sure: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Yes that's what I did. I pasted "[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=NbYkPQ5z" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/NbYkPQ5z/)" into the post but no luck

Comment: Yes, that's because you put an exclamation mark as a prefix. If you remove it, it should work. And please clarify your request. What would you like to achieve with the "pelvis" bone? What is the goal?

Comment: It's supposed to move the hips (and legs) but it moves the whole body. Also why are there connecting lines between the arm segments and hips?

Answer (score 1):

The way you can do that is by using ***IK***. You have to add ***Inverse Kinematics*** *Bone Constraints* to both "*calf bone*". Also, you need to create at least 2 (*1-1*) extra bones, but for more control, you can add even more. I used *2-2* bones and I gave them an "IK." prefix.

If you want to improve your rig, even more, I recommend your attention the following video:
[*Blender 2.8 Inverse Kinematics In 2 Minutes!*](http://%5B%3Cimg%20src=%22https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=q3v74GJG%22%20/%3E%5D(https://blend-exchange.com/b/q3v74GJG/))

Also here is the modified blend file:

[image]

I think the lines only represent the relations between the objects and the parent armature.